# Any coworking space in Nicosia, Cyprus?

Tags: work, cyprus

Can anyone give me a hint what it the closest option to coworking space in Nicosia?
For the next couple of weeks I desperately need a (reasonably priced) internet access, a table, an electrical outlet to plug in and a toilet.

The thing is I've rented apartments for next few months and was shocked to find out that connecting to fixed internet can take from 2 week to one month in average. 
I just can not afford such hiatus, so if I won't find a co-working space I'm lost.

Comment: Could you sit at a library?  Do you need internet day and night?

(I hesitate whether this question is on-topic here)

Comment: @gerrit, search "coworking" and you'll other questions alike. As for the library - well, it is a nice advise. If libraries here offers such services, well, i'll try it if won't find something more relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the most known one online appears to be the Urban Hive.  They have a [Facebook page with more information](https://www.facebook.com/urbanhivecy), but are located at:

Costa Ourani 8,

1076 Nicosia,

Cyprus

+357 22 447282

If that fails, [workspacesearch.com has a list of several other options](http://www.workspacesearch.com/list/coworking-space/Cyprus/-/-/Nicosia/list.html) you could consider.

Comment: This is permanently closed now. However, this one exists: https://www.yfantourgeio.com/

Answer (score -1):

Question is old, but I'm planning on visiting Cyprus soon - found this page with a few working spaces, two of them @ Nicosia and two more @ Paphos http://included.co/join/?in=cyprus

Comment: Are you involved in that site in any way? Or are you just a happy user who's found them useful elsewhere in the world?

Comment: Not involved with those sites @ Cyprus, have nothing to do included.co

Just thought it might be helped to be posted here, perhaps I should have commented it instead.